# Does a longer food duration mean more hp?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Does a longer duration of food mean more hp restoration. Or does it just take longer to gain the same amount of hp as any other food?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did a few experiments, and the answer depends on which kind of food it is. I found three different categories, though there might be more:

- food (raw meat, grilled chicken sandwich, ...)
- non-alcoholic drinks (milk, ...)
- alcoholic drinks (rivian kriek)

Each category has a different rate of health restoration, food has the highest at around 100/s, non-alcoholic drinks have a much lower value at around 30/s and alcoholic drinks have the lowest at around 20/s. Alcoholic drinks also have shorter restoration periods than the value listed in the inventory, that value is for how long the intoxication and screen blurring lasts, the 25s beers seem to have 15s of actual HP restoration time.

Ond food and one drink item stack, but not more. Non-alcoholic and alcoholic drinks don't stack, you can have only one active at any time.